# Does AngularJS run filter on every digest?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{type: 'book'}">
    {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

In this example, if `item.type` never changes in any of the `items`, nor does `items.length` as well as `item` objects, will AngularJS still run filter on every digest cycle?

Comment: Yes, that why the filter have to run fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every filter is executed every time a `$digest` cycle is initiated. It's the way Angular handle data-binding with the dirty checking.

For more informations, see this great article from Ben Nadel: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2489-how-often-do-filters-execute-in-angularjs.htm.